# TinyMCE: where to change the iframe src of the "visual" editor?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to add a (commercial) fonts.com font to the "visual" html wysiwyg editor. This does not work, because the "visual" editor iframe has `src='javascript:""'` which make requests from within the iframe missing the referrer header. However fonts.com (and other webfont provider) need a referrer to validate the request.

The solution is rather simple: use a (preferable blank) html page as source. Something like `blank.html`. I just don't find the corresponding code line.

**Where do I change the iframe src?** (I'm using TinyMCE inside of WP).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
$('#'+tinymce.editors[0].id+'_ifr').attr('src', 'blank.html');
```

or in case you know your editor id

```
$('#'+tinymce.get('your_editor_id')+'_ifr').attr('src', 'blank.html');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a way to change the src for initialization.

Comment: you could use the setup configuration parameter in combination with onInit whre you set the iframe source

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:setup ; instead onclick in the exapmle you use onInit